# Moment.Js date to week & year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

hi I would like to use moment js to pass the week and year number and he returns me "startOf" & "endOf" Step type Week = 22 Year = 2021and I would like him to
return
startOf = 31/05/2021
endOf = 06/06/2021

```
var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('week').toDate();
var endOfWeek   = moment().endOf('week').toDate();
```

Comment: You need to format the output.

Something like this I guess. 

var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('week').toDate("MM-DD-YYYY");


https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: THANKS the solution Hamada it's GOOD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let starDay = moment('2021').add(1, 'weeks').startOf('week').format('DD MM YYYY');
let endDay = moment('2021').add(1, 'weeks').endtOf('week').format('DD MM YYYY');
```

Comment: Thanks it's great